# Finding Number of COVID Re-transmissions

Tags: exponential-function

I had a thought to estimate how many times a virus is transmitted, on average, before infecting a given individual.

For instance, if Sample Virus has a re-transmission rate of 2, and a total infected population of 15, we can guess the virus has transmitted 3 times.  (1+2+4+8)

Given a re-transmission rate of 1.2, and a global infected population of 54 million, how many people can we estimate the COVID-19 virus has "gone through" before someone who has not been previously infected now contracts the virus?

This is not a homework question but I am having a lot of trouble finding a formula for this.
I used Excel auto-complete to repeatedly multiply the current population by 1.2 and found an answer of about 85 transmissions.  Is this the most accurate method here?  How can one find a formula for this answer?

Comment: It is really an interesting question. I am looking forward for the other approaches as well.

Comment: "how many people can we estimate the COVID-19 virus has gone through" : I'm not sure what you are asking.  Your math suggests that we are to assume the following: Start with a patient 0 (denote as Level 0).  Label each person infected by him as a Level 1 patient.  Label each person infected by a Level $n$ patient as a Level $(n+1)$ patient.  Assume that each Level $n$ patient infects $\approx$ 1.2 people, and then stops infecting people.  Then how many Levels of patients are represented by 54 million people. ...see next comment

Comment: Note that $1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^k ~=~ \frac{x^{(k+1)} - 1}{x - 1}.$  Therefore, you are looking for $(k)$ such that $\frac{(1.2)^{(k+1)} - 1}{1.2 - 1} \approx 54000000 \implies (1.2)^{(k+1)} \approx (0.2) \times 54000000.$  Taking the Log of both sides gives $(k+1) \approx \frac{[\log ~0.2] + [\log ~54000000]}{\log ~1.2} \approx 88.8 \implies ~k \approx 88.$  If you are asking a **different question** and want to flag me,  address a comment to @user2661923.

Comment: @user2661923 Hello, thank you for taking a look.  This was the question I was asking indeed and I think this is the most straightforward way to analyze it.  I recognize this is a series - what is the name for this particular one so I can brush up on it?  I am also curious if someone can expand on this, considering the available non-infected population decreases over time which may increase the ultimate result.  Does anyone know if similar calculations exist in the medical field for tracking things like mutation chance, etc.?

Comment: See [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).
As for your other questions, since I am totally ignorant here, all I 
can do is refer you to [Epidemiology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epidemiology).